# Number of pages in preamble

Tags: counters, preamble, lastpage

I have tried this to use the number of pages as an option to a package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{lastpage}
\usepackage{refcount}
\newcounter{mylastpage}
\setcounterpageref{mylastpage}{LastPage}
%\usepackage[\themylastpage]{package}
\begin{document}
    \themylastpage
    \setcounterpageref{mylastpage}{LastPage}
    \themylastpage
    \lipsum[1-100]
\end{document}
```

However, `\setcounterpageref` seem to work only in the document, not before. What else can I do? What I am trying to achieve is this:

```
\hypersetup{pdfprintpagerange=2 \themylastpage}
```

This shall skip printing the first two pages of my document by default; I know I have to adapt `\themylastpage` to account for numbering style or 0-based counting, but first things first...

Comment: Note that the setting of the printing page range will most likely only be usable inside Adobe Acrobat/Reader.

Comment: That's acceptable :)

Answer (score 3):

You could write the number of pages to a file at the very end of the document. That way you can read it in during your pages load (if it exists) and set content accordingly:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{atveryend}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\AtVeryEndDocument{%
  \newwrite\pagesfile% Create new write file
  \immediate\openout\pagesfile=\jobname.pages
  \immediate\write\pagesfile{% Write...
    \noexpand\newcounter{totalpages}% ...counter creation and...
    \noexpand\setcounter{totalpages}{\number\numexpr\value{page}-2}}% ...number of pages setting
  \immediate\closeout\pagesfile% Close file
}

% If the file already exists, read it in and set pdfprintpagerange
\InputIfFileExists{\jobname.pages}
  {\hypersetup{pdfprintpagerange=2 \thetotalpages}}
  {}

\begin{document}
Total pages: \ifcsname thetotalpages\endcsname
  \number\numexpr\value{totalpages}+1\relax
\fi

\sloppy% Just for this example
\lipsum[1-100]
\end{document}
```

The file `\jobname.pages` in the above creation should contain

```
\newcounter {totalpages} \setcounter {totalpages}{18}
```

Some things to note here:

1. The `page` counter is different to other counters in that it is initialized to 1.
2. Adobe uses a zero-based counter for the pages. This, together with (1) above makes for the need to store the value of the `page` counter *minus 2*. That's also why I add one to the displaying the page number inside the document itself (purely for aesthetics).
3. Many PDF document property settings only work for Adobe-related products.

Comment: I think your calculation is off by one. The pdf says `Total pages: 18`, but the file has 19 pages. Otherwise, nice solution. It's probably what `totcount` was made for (for lazy people like me).

Comment: @bers: That's true. I forgot to add one to the *display*. But for the `pdfprintpagerange` property it works as you're using a zero-based page enumeration and writing *after* the last shipout, so the `page` counter has been incremented once more. I've updated the *display* part of the minimal example.

Answer (score 1):

This finally works:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{lipsum}

% this is the solution
\usepackage{lastpage,refcount,totcount}
\newtotcounter{totlastpage}
\hypersetup{pdfprintpagerange=2 \the\totvalue{totlastpage}}
\AtBeginDocument{
    \setcounterpageref{totlastpage}{LastPage}
    \addtocounter{totlastpage}{-1}
}

\begin{document}
    \lipsum[1-100]
\end{document}
```

Is this a good way of doing it?